# Violación de segmento(`core' generado) en busqueda de maximo y minimo de una matriz dinámica

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema que me trae de cabeza un par de días. Estoy realizando un programa que busque el elemento máximo y mínimo dentro de una matriz dinámica mediante la técnica Divide y Vencerás. La cosa, es que ejecuto el programa y a la hora de dar el resultado, me sale el mensaje de error "Violación de segmento(`core' generado)" se que es por la condición siguiente:
`fil_ini < fil_fin && col_ini < col_fin`  pero si la cambio a `fil_ini < fil_fin-1 && col_ini < col_fin-1` si me ejecuta sin dar error pero da una solución incorrecta. Ya que lo que yo busco es que mi caso base para guardar el maximo y el minimo es que `fil_ini == fil_fin && col_ini == col_fin`

¿Que puedo hacer? ¿En que estoy fallando? Como puedo conseguir que de el resultado correcto sin que acceda a un area de memoria no permitida.

El codigo del programa entero es el siguiente:
(Como requisito se pide que n (dimensión de matriz) sea potencia de 2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;



void algoritmo_dyv(int **mat, int fil_ini, int fil_fin, int col_ini, int col_fin, int &max, int &min){
    int centro_f, centro_c;
    int max_1= 0, max_2= 0, max_3= 0, max_4= 0;
    int min_1= 100, min_2= 100, min_3= 100, min_4= 100;

    if(fil_ini < fil_fin-1 && col_ini < col_fin-1){
        centro_f= (fil_ini+fil_fin)/2;
        centro_c= (col_ini+col_fin)/2;
                algoritmo_dyv(mat,fil_ini,centro_f-1,col_ini,centro_c-1,max_1,min_1);   
        algoritmo_dyv(mat,centro_f,fil_fin,col_ini,centro_c-1,max_2,min_2);
        algoritmo_dyv(mat,centro_f,fil_fin,centro_c,col_fin,max_3,min_3);       
        algoritmo_dyv(mat,fil_ini,centro_f-1,centro_c,col_fin,max_4,min_4);
    //COMBINAR

        if(max_1 > max_2 && max_1 > max_3 && max_1 > max_4 && max_1 > max){
            max= max_1;
        }else if(max_2 > max_1 && max_2 > max_3 && max_2 > max_4 && max_2 > max){
            max= max_2;
        }else if(max_3 > max_1 && max_3 > max_2 && max_3 > max_4 && max_3 > max){
            max= max_3;
        }else if(max_4 > max_1 && max_4 > max_2 && max_4 > max_3 && max_4 > max){
            max= max_4;
        }

        if(min_1 < min_2 && min_1 < min_3 && min_1 < min_4 && min_1 < min){
            min= min_1;
        }else if(min_2 < min_1 && min_2 < min_3 && min_2 < min_4 && min_2 < min){
            min= min_2;
        }else if(min_3 < min_2 && min_3 < min_1 && min_3 < min_4 && min_3 < min){
            min= min_3;
        }else if(min_4 < min_1 && min_4 < min_2 && min_4 < min_3 && min_4 < min){
            min= min_4;
        }

    //CASO BASE

    }else{
            max= min= mat[fil_ini][col_ini];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int n;
    int num;
    int max= 0, min= 100;
    int **mat;
    struct timespec t0, t1;
    double time;

    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr<<"\nError: El programa se debe ejecutar de la siguiente forma.\n\n";
        cerr<<" ./basico tamCaso\n\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    n= atoi(argv[1]);

    if((n & (n-1)) == 0){
        cout <<"\nDimension es potencia de dos. "<< endl;
    }else{
        cout <<"\nDimension no es potencia de dos. "<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    mat= new int*[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        mat[i]= new int[n];
    }

    cout <<"\nLlenando matriz con numeros aleatorios...";

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            mat[i][j]= rand() % 101;
        }
    }



    cout <<"\nMatriz llena."<< endl;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            cout << mat[i][j] <<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&t0); 
    algoritmo_dyv(mat,0,n,0,n,max,min);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&t1);

    time=(double)(t1.tv_sec -t0.tv_sec) + (double)(t1.tv_nsec - t0.tv_nsec)/(1.e+9);

    cout <<"\nTiempo de ejecucion: "<< time << endl;

    cout <<"\nSoluc "<< max <<" "<< min << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        delete[] mat[i];
    }

    delete[] mat;

    return 0;
}
```

Salu2 camaradas!

Comment: Hola. Yo entiendo que si tu matriz va desde 0 hasta n-1, cuando pases ese valor de n a la función, también la deberás de recorrer desde 0 hasta n-1, o te dará el error que describes. Si no te funciona bien el algoritmo será debido a otro problema, pero no al hecho de recorrer el array entre esos valores.

Comment: Si, de tanto tocar se me olvido poner en la llamada a la función de nuevo los n-1 pero aun con eso, me sigue dando ese error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estás gestionando correctamente los límites de cada subcaso:

```
algoritmo_dyv(mat,0,n,0,n,max,min);
```

Aquí estás asumiendo que `n` **no es un elemento a buscar**, es decir, queda fuera de la búsqueda...

```
algoritmo_dyv(mat,fil_ini,centro_f-1,col_ini,centro_c-1,max_1,min_1);   
algoritmo_dyv(mat,centro_f,fil_fin,col_ini,centro_c-1,max_2,min_2);
algoritmo_dyv(mat,centro_f,fil_fin,centro_c,col_fin,max_3,min_3);       
algoritmo_dyv(mat,fil_ini,centro_f-1,centro_c,col_fin,max_4,min_4);
```

Aquí sin embargo la cosa cambia... fíjate que a `centro_f` y `centro_c` le restas 1 cuando los pasas como límite superior, es decir, que `centro_f-1` y `centro_c-1` **quedan fuera** de la búsqueda.

Prueba así:

```
    algoritmo_dyv(mat,fil_ini,centro_f,col_ini,centro_c,max_1,min_1);   
    algoritmo_dyv(mat,centro_f,fil_fin,col_ini,centro_c,max_2,min_2);
    algoritmo_dyv(mat,centro_f,fil_fin,centro_c,col_fin,max_3,min_3);       
    algoritmo_dyv(mat,fil_ini,centro_f,centro_c,col_fin,max_4,min_4);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ha funcionado, el programa ya no da violación de segmento! Todo arreglado, lo agradezco mucho, salu2!